# config urlManager yii such as facebook

Tags: yii2, yii-url-manager

I want to give this address
I want to display just username in the address.

```
            '{username}'=>'site/user<username:{username}>'
```

'urlManager' => [

```
    'showScriptName' => false,  

    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,   


    'rules' =>

        [

            '{username}'=>'site/user<username:{username}>',


        ]
        ,
],
```

How to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl'=>true,
    'showScriptName'=>false,
    ....
    'rules' => [
         '<username:[a-zA-Z0-9_ -]+>' => 'site/user',
          ....
    ],
]
```

Comment: Your solution worked for me ... but this does not work now
                    '<action>'=>'site/<action>'

Comment: it is because all requests are treated as requests for the actionUser. you should change url rules, like this: 'rules' => ['user/<username:[a-zA-Z0-9_ -]+>' => 'site/user', '<action>'=>'site/<action>']. and if you go to example.com/user/my_user_name, you will get actionUser(). if you go to example.com/otheraction, you will get the actionOtheraction in the SiteController. BUT, if you have another controllers, you should change the rules in your config to allow for all controllers.